# Nlog Error when setting property 'Layout' on File Target[file]

Tags: nlog

I have a problem when i use nlog for error and logging. Here is my code :

Error : Error when setting property 'Layout' on File Target[file]

Nlog.config

```xml
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"   layout="${date}|${level}|${logger}|${steps_guid}|${machinename}|${windows-identity:domain=false}--${message} ${exception:format=message,stacktrace:separator=*"  fileName="E:\myapplication.log" />
<target xsi:type="Database" name="database" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True" commandText="exec [dbo].[LOGINNG_CREATE]    @steps_guid,@log_application ,@log_date,@log_level ,@log_logger ,   @log_message ,@log_machine_name ,   @log_user_name ,@log_call_site ,@log_thread ,@log_exception ,   @log_stacktrace ">
  <parameter name="@steps_guid" layout="${steps_guid}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_application" layout="${application}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_date" layout="${date}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_level" layout="${level}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_logger" layout="${logger}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_message" layout="${message}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_machine_name" layout="${machinename}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_user_name" layout="${windows-identity:domain=true}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_call_site" layout="${callsite:filename=true}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_thread" layout="${threadid}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_exception" layout="${exception}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_stacktrace" layout="${stacktrace}"/>

</target>
```

and c# code and i dont know is it necessary:

```cs
Logger loggerClass = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("steps_guid", steps_guid);
return loggerClass;
```

and i use it like this :

```cs
  public bool Login(Entity.USERS user)
    {
        try
        {
           this.PageRepository = new xxx.Business.UserBusiness();
            logger.Info("User service's instance created");
            return this.PageRepository.Login(user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.ErrorException("User services login Error", ex);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are missing the closing `}` in your `layout`. It should be `layout="${date}|${level}|${logger}|${steps_guid}|${machinename}|${windows-identity:domain=false}--${message} ${exception:format=message,stacktrace:separator=*}"`

Comment: @namesv, I guess you're right, try that and tell us how it goes. Also: why is this question tagged as WCF?

Comment: I had the same issue but my problem was the .Net version of something explained in an inner exception. Just leaving it here since this is what is first hit by google. My fix was to downgrade dependency.abstraction from 2.1.1.0 to 2.0.0.0.